# i have open pdf file in php and how can secure it ? no one can neither download nor print it

Tags: php

I run PDF file through localhost in php there is a option in browser of printing the PDF and I dont want it to be print. 
Here is my code:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('The C# 4.0 complete reference.pdf');
die();
```

kindly help me

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to do exactly. Where is the file stored?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   <?php
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");

    // It will be called downloaded.pdf
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");

    // The PDF source is in original.pdf
    readfile("original.pdf");
    ?>
```

Comment: i have try it previously but in browser on left click you get an option of print and i dont want print option for my pdf